# TJson.JsonToObject<T> throws errors in a multi-thread environment

Tags: json, multithreading, delphi, rest, delphi-xe7

When using `TJson.JsonToObject` in a multi-thread environment random access violations occur. I was searching a long time for the problem and I could isolate it with the following code

JSON class

```
type
   TParameter = class
   public
      FName     : string;
      FDataType : string;
      FValue    : string;
   end;
```

Testfunction:

```
procedure Test();
var
   myTasks: array of ITask;
   i : integer;
   max : integer;
begin

  max := 50;
  SetLength(myTasks, max);
  for i := 0 to max  -1  do begin
     myTasks[i] := TTask.Create(procedure ()
       var
          json : string;
          p : TParameter;
       begin
          json := '{"name":"NameOfParam","dataType":"TypeOfParam","value":"ValueOfParam"}';
          p := TJson.JsonToObject<TParameter>(json);
          p.Free;
       end);
     myTasks[i].Start;
  end;

  TTask.WaitForAll(myTasks);
  ShowMessage('all done!');
end;
```

It's only a code snippet based of a much more complex source. As long I use this code in a single thread everything works without a problem. I'm wondering if there is anything wrong with the code.

Comment: Which JSON library? Is it known to be thread safe? Why with a lock around the call to `JsonToObject`. If the code runs well with the lock, and fails without then that would point to `JsonToObject` not being thread safe.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this. Just setting up a console application and putting your `TParameter` in a separate unit seems to work fine, no exceptions.Addings a `WriteLn( TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID );` to the `Proc` of your `TTask` also shows that de-serialization occurs from different threads.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the Library is from embarcadero REST.Json

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful i tried it with a console application but had the same problem, do you have installed any xe7 patches?

Comment: @deterministicFail I have to revoke my hasty statement. I'm running XE7 without Update 1. When running the tasks in a `TThreadPool` with the minimum number of worker threads set to greater than one, it fails sooner or later. The higher the number, the sooner it crashes.

Comment: I think that the problem is in the RTTI. It's just not thread-safe. For instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368556/trtticontext-multi-thread-issue  I expect that there are more problems along these lines

Comment: Yes, I'm confident that there's a thread safety issue. If I serialize the execution of `TJSONUnMarshal.CreateObject` then there are no errors. I think you need to submit a bug report. You've got a beautiful reproduction.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The method `TJSONUnMarshal.ObjectInstance` in `REST.JsonReflect.pas` has a severe bug:

It calls FreeAndNil on a TRttiType instance. This should **never** be done because all TRtti*** instances are managed by the TRttiContext.

After I removed the FreeAndNil call I could not reproduce the access violation anymore.

Reported as: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-10035

P.S. I also think that https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9815 will affect your code.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this and reporting +1

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort

Comment: +1 and a question: from the bug report it is not clear if only the Generic method call is affected (TJson.JsonToObject<TParameter>(json) - in a XE7 application I see sporadic AVs, it uses  TJson.JsonToObject(FSomeField, SomeJsonObject);